# Turn dict into list wipes out the values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Short question: Why when we do list(dict()) the return is the keys of the dict, but not the values?
Cause all that I know about (key, value) pairs, is that what matters is the value, not the key. The key it's just a page in a book. Since we don't actually want the page, but the content of that page, giving me the page makes no sense at all at first.

I believe that it, somehow, makes sense. But please, clarify this one.

Thanks!

**EDITED:**
now, since the most relevant part of a (key, value) pair ITS THE VALUE. Why not the the **iter** method of dict returns the value?

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary yields the keys. That's just how it was implemented. Why would you want the values instead of the keys? You can go from key to value, but you can't go from value to key. If you want the values, there's `d.values()`. If you want a list of key-value tuples, there's `d.items()`.

Comment: You were looking for `d.items()`

Comment: Can you share some of what you're trying to do?  What is the goal of your program, or the piece of it you're working on?

Comment: @Blender I want the values cause the values is what matters! What's the logic of having page numbers if you don't know which page is related to which book? And I know we have some workaround. And if we wanted key we would use d.keys(), right? But why return the keys when building the list and not the values?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Actually I was thinking of something that led me to this. Than I questioned myself. And now you guys.

Comment: @PatrickBassut: If you want the values, then use `d.values()`. I've rarely used the values of a dictionary explicitly, which leads me to believe that the Python devs had good reasons for choosing to have `dict.__iter__` yield the keys instead of the values. You can email them and ask if you want. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: "what matters is the value, not the key" is a rubbish statement.  they both matter.  if the key doesn't matter, then you use a list or a set.

Comment: I would argue that the key is not analogous to a page in a book, but more to a word in a dictionary.   If I want to look up a definition, it's more important to know the word.  If all I knew was the definition, I would probably have a hard time finding the corresponding word.  But, if I have a bunch of the words, I can easily look up the definition in the dictionary. That's probably why they're called dictionaries, not books.

Comment: @wim You guys are right.

Comment: We agreed that the value is not the most important. But does that mean that the key is the most important part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this occurs is because `list` accepts an iterator, and uses each item as if it was an iterator by calling `iter` on it.  Since the `__iter__` method of the `dict` type returns an iterator over it's keys, calling `list` on a `dict` object gives you it's keys.

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __iter__(self):
        print 'iter on A'
        return iter(self.lst)


>>> a = A(range(10))
>>> list(a)
iter on A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In terms of implementation, returning only keys would be the faster than returning both, and since they explicitly include an `items` method, there doesn't exist a very good reason for including values in the default `__iter__` implementation.  [Implementation of DICT](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/) The [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) data from python indicate that iterating over keys is `O(n)` and retrieving values is `O(1)`, which may seem insignificant, until you realize that iterating and retrieving values given keys is `O(n)` also.  This would be wasteful unless you really wanted the key,value pairs (as opposed to just keys, or just values), so it's not the default.

If you wanted it to be the default, you could do this:

```
class myDict(dict):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iteritems()
```

and calling `list` on an instance of `myDict` will give you key, value pairs.

Comment: Yea, got it! Okay! But WHY the __iter__ method of dicts returns the KEY, and not THE VALUE!? Question edited.

Answer (score 5):

It is simply untrue that the value is "the most relevant part" of the key-value pair.  The pair itself is what is relevant.  That's why you're using a dict.  If all you wanted was the values, you'd just use a list.

Also, as @Blender rightly points out, if you know the key, you can easily get the value, whereas the reverse is not true.  So if you're only going to get one, it definitely makes sense to get the key and not the value.

Although it's true that `in` and iteration behavior are not necessarily linked, it's also true that for most other container types, iterating over the container yields all and only the items for which `item in container` would be true.  I seem to recall seeing threads on comp.lang.python at one point where people said that the decision to make `in` on dictionaries work by key, and to make iteration work like `in`, was made a long time ago and then maintained for backwards compatibility, although I can't find any references for that right now.

It is legitimate to wonder why iterating overa  dict yields the keys and not the key/value pairs.  But the answer to this is just "that's the way the dict API specifies it".  Iterating over the key-value pairs (or the values alone, if it comes to that) is so trivially easy, with a single method call, that it hardly matters which one is the default behavior.

Comment: BrenBarn said it better than I did. +1

Answer (score 0):

> Why when we do `list(dict())` the return is the keys of the dict, but
>   not the values?

First, doing `dict()` will not return any keys or values, but an empty dictionary. You are calling the built-in `dict` function.

If you type exactly that in the shell, you'll end up with an empty list `[]`.

By the way, you also can't do:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
list(d())
```

This will raise a `TypeError` since dictionary objects are not callable.

By default if you loop over a dictionary, due to its implementation, the default iterator will return keys. This is the straight forward answer to your question. The reason for this implementation is that in Python, there is only *one* type that you can use to retrieve values by using any hashable type, and that is a dictionary. Hence, the primary use case for this type would be to retrieve items by their key, which can be any arbitrary value. In addition, since dictionaries are unordered getting easy access to the keys is the easiest way and I would argue the *primary reason* to even use a dictionary. Otherwise, what's wrong with a list? or tuple?

---

If you have a dictionary and you want to convert it to a list, you need to somehow 'flatten' the dictionary. This is because lists already have a 0-indexed key, which I am sure you already know.

To get `list(somedict)` to create a list of the *values* of any dictionary, you have a few ways.

The first one which was hinted in the comments; and is the most straightforward way:

```
list({'a': 1, 'b': 2}.values())
```

If you want to add some syntactic sugar on it, but this is just being silly:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.values
list(d())
```

Finally, if you want to have both the keys and the values in your list, you can do this:

```
list({'a': 1, 'b': 2}.values())
[('a', 1),('b', 2)]
```

Now you have a list of tuples, each representing a key/value pair. Some developers use this to sort the dictionary as dictionaries are unsorted in Python.  In Python 2.7, [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) was added to the `collections` module, which provides sorted dictionaries.

Comment: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}.values() seems more straightforward.

Comment: doing list(dict()) was just a wrong example that everybody got the concept. Sorry about that.